# Any sms gateway providing free service for only receiving incoming SMS from one mobile number? in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to receive the incoming SMS from one particular mobile number. I should not send SMS to anywhere. So i need a free SMS gateway or any plugin or gem do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to use the data received by SMS for further processing you can try [txtWeb](http://www.txtweb.com/) service provided by intuit.
It is free.

Comment: Thans for your reply. My need is actually i will retrieve the sms from one mobile number and stored in my database. "txtWeb" is working for ruby on rails?

Comment: Get a "short code" service